# What could be the source of error for this kind of android wireless (wifi) disconnection?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, connection-issues, stock-android, lg-g2

Recently there was wifi connection problem for my LG G2 (Android 4.4.2). It has internet connection and was able to connect to AP but sometimes it faces connection drop, no wifi connected although the wifi trigger was still on. During the connection drop, the phone appears to linked to wifi, but i noticed there is no data connection when i monitored live using some wireless monitoring tool. The wifi auto disconnect even i have the strongest signal connection (router was just below my desk) and there was proper internet connection for my laptop which is connected to the same AP.

Thus i would like to be advised is this the source of error from the hardware itself, or from the stock LG G2 ROM (Software)?.

Thanks

Edit: It occurs in each router that i connects

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the channel of your wireless router. Maybe it was caused by the congestion of the working channel(Maybe channel 1).

Comment: Rather unlikely, as the OP states: *It occurs in each router that i connect* – so it's not just the router he might have access to for configuring it.